# Using properties of determinants with row operations

Tags: matrices, determinant

[image]

My attempt: Multiples of rows are being added to other rows (should have no effect). V1 is multiplied by $7$ (determinant x 7) and V4 by 9 (determinant x 9), so final determinant should be 4 x 7 x 9 = $252$.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I got the right answer but can somebody explain why in user8795's answer, the final answer is not multiplied by 1/2 x 1/2 to change the second and third row from $2v_2$ and $2v_3$  to $v_2$ and $v_3$, since that's what's there in the given matrix?

Comment: It's not the correct answer

Comment: The matrix in question is $BA$ where $B=\pmatrix{7&0&0&2\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\5&0&0&9}$. What is $\det B$?

Comment: Is the answer 53??

Comment: the answer is not 53

Comment: how did you get B? and what is wrong with my thought process?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
\begin{bmatrix}
    7v_1 +2v_4     \\
    2v_2      \\
    2v_3    \\
    5v_1+9v_4
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
    7v_1      \\
    v_2      \\
    v_3    \\
    9v_4
\end{bmatrix}

+\begin{bmatrix}
    2v_4     \\
    v_2      \\
    v_3    \\
    5v_1
\end{bmatrix}
=$7\times9 \times4- 5 \times2\times4 = 53\times4$

Comment: There were some extra $2$’s in the last matrix but fine now, +1

Comment: why is the (54 x 4) not multiplied by 1/4 in the end to remove the 2 from row 3 and row 4?

Comment: yes you have to do 1/4 on both sides to adjust so i have written in that fashon

Comment: 53 x 4 x (1/4) $doesn't$ give the right answer. The right answer is 53 x 4 = 212

Comment: Also how are you adding the determinants like that, what property are you using?

Comment: @user8795 ........?